# $I=\langle x \rangle \in \mathbb{F}_2$ . Show that $\textit{I}(V(I))=\langle x, y^2-y \rangle $

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{F}_2$ be a field with of two elements and let $I=\langle x \rangle \in \mathbb{F}_2[x,y]$ . Show that $\textit{I}(V(I))=\langle x, y^2-y \rangle $. This is bigger than √I and is not a monomial ideal.
This is an exercise from Ideals, Varities and Algorithms book but im very stuck in this excerse, any hint?

Comment: What is $\;x\;$ ? What does $\;\langle x\rangle\;$ mean? Is that the non-zero element of $\;\Bbb F_2\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry i just correct the question its the ideal generated by $x$

Comment: How is $V(I)$ defined for you? Often enough we go to an algebraic closure (to get Nullstellensatz and all that). So $(0,\alpha)\in V(\langle x\rangle)$ for every $\alpha\in\overline{\Bbb{F}_2}$. But there is no need for $\alpha$ to be a zero of $y^2-y$ (unless $\alpha$ is in the prime field).

Comment: $V(I)$ are the points $a$ in the affine space such that $f(a)=0$ for $f \in I$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen the excercise wants to show that $k$ must be algebraic closure for hilbert function degree

Comment: What have you tried? did you show any of the inclusions?

Comment: The affine space $\;\Bbb F_2^2\;$ , right?

Comment: Also try solving this simpler 1 dimension lower question: Show $I(V(I))=\langle y^2-y \rangle$ where $I=0\subseteq \mathbb F_2[y]$

Answer (score 2):

Well, clearly $\;V(I)=\{(0,a)\in F_2^2\}\;$, and thus

$$I(V(I)):=\left\{g\in\Bbb F_2[x,y]\;: g(0,a)=0\;\;\forall\,(0,a)\in V(I)\right\}\;$$

But since $\;a\in\{0,1\}\pmod 2\;$, we have that

$$g(I(V(I))\iff g(0,0)=g(0,1)=0\,,\,\,\text{since in fact}\;\;V(I)=\{(0,0), (0,1)\}$$

We are not going up to a (the) algebraic closure of $\;\Bbb F_2\;$ for this since you're not mentioning any of this.